# Relations between F distribution, Chi-squared distribution, t distribution in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to produce some Matlab pictures which can confirm the following well known relations

[image]

This is my attempt for the first relation

```
clear
m=30;
n=1000; %almost inf
x = 0:.1:20;
pdf_F=m*pdf('F', x, m, n);   
plot(x,pdf_F,'LineWidth',2)
hold on
pdf_Chisquare=pdf('Chisquare', x, m)/m;
plot(x,pdf_Chisquare,'LineWidth',2)
hold off
legend('m*F_{m,\infty}',   'X^2_m')
```

which produces this picture [image]

This is my attempt for the first relation

```
clear
m=30;
x = 0:.1:20;
pdf_F=pdf('F', x, 1, m);   
plot(x,pdf_F,'LineWidth',2)
hold on
pdf_T=(pdf('T', x, m)).^2;
plot(x,pdf_T,'LineWidth',2)
hold off
legend('F_{1,m}',   't^2_m')
```

which produces this picture [image]

The pictures do not confirm the relations stated at the beginning. Could you help me to fix the codes?

Comment: I think you are confusing the values of the random variable with the values of its pdf. In fact, the wording in the text (image) you show is confusing. For example, the first expression, "m F_{m,inf} ~ X^2_m" does _not_ mean that you should multiply the first pdf by _m_. It means that if the F-distributed random variable is multiplied by _m_, the resulting variable has an X^2 distribution

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, got it.